# React -- Mapping specific images to specific cards

Tags: reactjs, json, mapping

Trying to map specific images to specific card components as backgrounds. **Problem** -  When I pass data.bgUrl into  `` style={{ backgroundImage:`url(${data.bgUrl})`}} `` the result is surrounded by quotes ("img1") instead of just path name (img1). As a result, images won't load. Any insights?

```
import AthleteData from "../athletes.json";
import img1 from "../assets/img1.png";
import img2 from "../assets/img2.png";
import img3 from "../assets/img3.png";
import img4 from "../assets/img4.png";
....etc
import Card from "./Card";
import "./cards.scss";

export default function Cards() {
  return (
    <div className="cards-container">
      <div className="cards">
        {AthleteData.map((data, key) => {
          return (
            <div
              key={key}
              style={{
                backgroundImage: `url(${data.bgUrl})`,
              }}
            >
              <Card
                key={key}
                name={data.name}
                date={data.date}
                link={data.link}
              />
            </div>
          );
        })}
      </div>
      <h3>Load More Cards</h3>
    </div>
  );
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you used `backgroundImage` in style, you don't need to import images. Please check your `data.bgUrl` is the correct path for each image.
also, set the image size through `width` and `height`, or `backgroundSize` in the style. You may need to set `backgroundRepeat` in the style as well.

Answer (score 0):

I'm assuming that the 'AthleteData' you are importing is an object where one of the properties is called 'bgUrl' and that the value of that property is set to be a string such as 'img1'. The problem with that, if it is the case, is that the line where you are attempting to call that property (of bgURL) is that it still only represents a string, even if you have an imported variable that is called 'img1' as well. In your Athletes.json file you would want to have a dynamic reference to the image location. The problem with this is that .json files don't support import statements.

What I would recommend doing is to make a simple Javascript file where you import all your images as you did above and set them into a single object below them. Set the property 'bgUrl' to the dynamic references that those import statements create, and then you should be good. I will demonstrate below:

```js
//This would be the new athletes.js file. Not a .json file
import img1 from "../assets/img1.png";
import img2 from "../assets/img2.png";
import img3 from "../assets/img3.png";
import img4 from "../assets/img4.png";
....etc

const AthleteData =
[
  {name: 'Athlete1', bgUrl:img1, ...},
  {name: 'Athlete2', bgUrl:img2, ...},
  {name: 'Athlete3', bgUrl:img3, ...}
]

export default AthleteData
```

Then when you import this and use it in your jsx it would look like so:

```js
import AthleteData from "../athletes.js";
// No longer importing those image refrences here

import Card from "./Card";
import "./cards.scss";

export default function Cards() {
  return (
    <div className="cards-container">
      <div className="cards">
        {AthleteData.map((data, key) => {
          return (
            <div
              key={key}
              style={{
                backgroundImage: `url(${data.bgUrl})`,
              }}
            >
              <Card
                key={key}
                name={data.name}
                date={data.date}
                link={data.link}
              />
            </div>
          );
        })}
      </div>
      <h3>Load More Cards</h3>
    </div>
  );
}
```

Everything should roughly be the same in your jsx but you wouldn't need the import statements.

Comment: Thanks for your thorough reply, Vidal!